# How to detect OS language in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone, detect

So before I used:

```
 System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
```

How to do it in Wp8.1. And why all the deprecated things dont have a good documentation what you can use instead like in xCode?

Comment: Why doesn't that line work? There is also [this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentuiculture(v=vs.110).aspx), which says it works in WP 8.1

Comment: It works like this CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name

Comment: So, you have your answer? If so, self answer using the button below (get some extra rep).

Comment: CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name.ToString() returns en-EN, despite my OS is in german??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**CultureInfo.CurrentCulture used to return the region format setting. WP 8.1 seems to return the default language set in the Package.appxmanifest.**

Kinda sucks doesn't it? :)

I think it is planned because they want to steer us towards using `GlobalizationPreferences` instead.  So to get back to what you want....you need to do something like this:

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(Windows.System.UserProfile.GlobalizationPreferences.Languages[0]);
```

It basically creates a CultureInfo based on their prefer top language (which I think is the display UI).

Good luck :)

Comment: Does not really work. My phone was running 'de-DE' and I switched to 'de-CH' to test if the app adapts the currency symbols and stuff. 'de-CH' is on index 1, though it's the primary language. I guess Microsoft has managed to make something easy terribly difficult.