# Get Current Region of Windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am just facing a problem in getting the user set region in **Windows Phone 8.1 (SilverLight)**.

**Situation:**  I have set the Region to `United Kingdom` and the language to `English(United States)` (it is valid to do that).

In that case I am still getting the region `UnitedState(US)` via these methods:

- `RegionInfo`
- `Thread.CurrentThread`
- `System.Globalization`

  ```
  private static void GetRegion()
  {
      // all of the three returing UnitedStates.
      var dfg = RegionInfo.CurrentRegion;
      var cuture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
      var cul = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
  }
  ```

Why do these not return `United Kingdom` as a region?

Comment: How did you set the region? Did you set it correctly?

Comment: @xmashallax Yes, I had. I went to setting => region=> selected UnitedKingdom -(haven't change the language) => restarted phone => check again for region => it UK.

Comment: Take a look at this StackO question/answers maybe you can find more info there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560412/winrt-apps-and-regional-settings-the-correct-way-to-format-dates-and-numbers-ba

Answer (score 5):

Building on my previous answer: [Detect OS Language WP 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26017809/how-to-detect-os-language-in-windows-phone-8-1/26030904#26030904)

```C#
string region =
    Windows.System.UserProfile.GlobalizationPreferences.HomeGeographicRegion;
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that I am developing on WP8.1 silverlight.

Comment: @loop ah I see, looks like the only fixed it in 8.1 runtime, see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17675081/get-country-region-name-from-windows-phone-8

Comment: thanks for the reference but really can't use that.That is not a good solution. :(

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `RegionInfo.CurrentRegion` property as mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.regioninfo.currentregion(v=vs.110).aspx) which you normally use for WP8 or WP8.1.

[Detecting home country of Windows Phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223295/)

Comment: not helpful already checked that.. I do not want the change in language. that is working. I want the change in country that can be changed without the change in language.